# sendSubviewToBack on UITableView not working properly in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, ios11

I have an UITableViewController to which I successfully applied in the past a gradient background, by sending the newly added subview to back:

```
//performed on viewDidLoad
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.5*280, 1.5*SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = bgView.bounds;
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
UIColor *topColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x229f80);
UIColor *bottomColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x621ad9);
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[topColor CGColor], (id)[bottomColor CGColor], nil];
[bgView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:bgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];
bgView = nil;
```

However, this no longer works in iOS 11 and the bgView is actually placed on top of all the cells.

[image]

Anyone knows how I can fix this?
Or maybe I was doing it wrong all the time?

Comment: [self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView]; instead of this,try this method - (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cells are transparent then you can try `self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView;`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the background view to be scrolling together with the table view, you can use

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView;
```

If you need the background view to be scrolling, change layer's `zPosition` to a negative value to make it work in iOS 11:

```
[self.view insertSubview:bgView atIndex:0];
bgView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
bgView.layer.zPosition = -1;
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was zPosition I overlooked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to fix it is to call `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];` in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

It works for not transparent cells also.

Comment: But this will try to send the subview each time a cell is displayed, which I think is redundant.

Comment: If you won't do it each time a cell is displayed then every newer cell (returned by cellForRow) will be under this view.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that addSubview(UIView) sendSubview(toBack: UIView) no longer works for UITableViewControllers in iOS11. So I swap to this:

```
// in ViewDidLoad
// set the backgroundImage
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "background.png")
//        self.view.addSubview(backgroundImage) // NO LONGER WORKS
//        self.view.sendSubview(toBack: backgroundImage) // NO LONGER WORKS
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImage
```